# The CSS attribute will not stay after the jquery runs

Tags: jquery, css

The class "active" should make the nav item glow.

http://kevinmikol.com/dmi/home

```
(function($) {
  var currentRadius, multiplier;

  function parseOptions(options) {
    return {
      RADIUS:     (options.radius    || 20),
      DURATION:   (options.duration  || 500),
      TEXT_COLOR: (options.textColor || '#fff'),
      HALO_COLOR: (options.haloColor || '#777')
    }
  }

  function currentRadius(elem) {
    if (prop = elem.style['text-shadow']) {
      return parseInt(prop.match(/0 0 (\d+)px/));
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  function stepTextShadow(fx) {
    if (fx.state == 0) {
      fx.start = currentRadius(fx.elem);
    }

    updatedRadius = fx.end.begin ?
      parseInt(fx.end.radius * fx.pos) :
      parseInt(fx.end.radius - (fx.end.radius * fx.pos))

    if (fx.end.begin || (fx.state < 1)) {
      $(fx.elem).css('text-shadow', fx.end.color + ' 0 0 ' + updatedRadius + 'px');
    } else {
      $(fx.elem).css('text-shadow', $(fx.elem).data('glow.originalGlow'));
    }
  }

  function addGlow(opts) {
    var opts = parseOptions(opts || { });

    function startGlow() {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        color: opts.TEXT_COLOR,
        textShadow: {
          begin: true,
          color: opts.HALO_COLOR,
          radius: opts.RADIUS
        }
      }, opts.DURATION);
    }

    function startFade() {
      $(this).stop().animate({
        color: $(this).data('glow.originColor'),
        textShadow: {
          begin: false,
          color: opts.HALO_COLOR,
          radius: opts.RADIUS
        }
      }, opts.DURATION);
    }

    with($(this)) {
      bind('mouseenter', startGlow);
      bind('mouseleave', startFade);
      data('glow.originColor', css('color'));
      data('glow.originalGlow', (css('text-shadow') || 'none'));
    }

    return this;
  }

  $.fx.step['textShadow'] = stepTextShadow;
  $.fn.addGlow = addGlow;
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am using Jquery glow and the css attribute that should show the current page nulls after the jquery glow runs

Comment: We need to see samples of how you are using it, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: http://kevinmikol.com/dmi/js/glow/jquery-glowing.js

Comment: #nav li.active{color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-shadow: rgb(255, 0, 0) 0px 0px 20px; }  It should glow on hover and then still glow if it is the current page

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood. When Hovered Over the Clicked page the glow disappears it is because When hovered the `a` tag in the `li` class `active` is getting the attribute `display none`. So If You add a script such that for every hover of the nav tabs you can check if the class of the `li is active` if the class of the `li` is active You can use

```
$('.active').find('a').attr('style','');
```

Of couse You have  given the style for `active` class using css. But Inline styleing will override css styling always.

hope this helps.